# How do I SSH into my microcomputer running arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi

I am doing the [kerberos.io raspberry pi security camera project](http://%3Ca%20href=%22https://doc.kerberos.io/1.0/installation%22%3Eproject%3C/a%3E).

I got to step 5 and am having trouble with getting a command script to appear along with being able to SSH into the Pi.

Per instructions I am using the following credentials to SSH: `ssh root@ 192.168.0.10` and the standard password: `root`

This is the output I get with `ssh -v host:`

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011 
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config 
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for * 
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for * 
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.10 [192.168.0.10] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.10 port 22: Operation timed out ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.10 port 22: Operation timed out 
Connors-MacBook-Pro:~ Connor$
```

Comment: what about the whitespace between `@` and ipaddress? Can you provide what error you got?

Comment: Did you mean step 6? Also, could you provide more details of what kind of error you are getting?. It would be useful if you try to ssh to it using ssh-v, so use: `ssh -v root@192.168.0.10` and output the result here.

Comment: @SaulOrtega yes. here is the result: 

`OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.10 [192.168.0.10] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.10 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.10 port 22: Operation timed out
Connors-MacBook-Pro:~ Connor$ `

Comment: Ping to that ip to see if you can see it. It seems like there's no connection/It can't find that ip address.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either the machine isn't listening on port 22 or you are trying to ssh into with the wrong IP address.

Try mapping your LAN for machines listening on SSH port 22:

Command to map with nmap:

`nmap -p 22 --open -sV 192.168.1.0/24`

It also looks like you are thinking it will be on 192.168.0.something, so try this too:

`nmap -p 22 --open -sV 192.168.0.0/24`

Here's what my output looks like, with 192.168.1.7 being my Pi:

```
treddell@laptop:~$ nmap -p 22 --open -sV 192.168.1.0/24

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-08-18 15:10 MST
Nmap scan report for WL.ph.cox.net (192.168.1.1)
Host is up (0.0012s latency).
The 1 scanned port on WL.ph.cox.net (192.168.1.1) is closed

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.5
Host is up (0.093s latency).
The 1 scanned port on 192.168.1.5 is closed

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.6
Host is up (0.00015s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 5.9p1 Debian 5ubuntu1.6 (protocol 2.0)
Service Info: OS: Linux

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.7
Host is up (0.061s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 6.0p1 Debian 4+deb7u2 (protocol 2.0)
Service Info: OS: Linux

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (4 hosts up) scanned in 3.97 seconds
```

Once you get it's IP address for certain then use this command:

`ssh root@192.168.x.x`

replacing the x's with the numbers you found. Note that I would avoid the space after '@' that you had.